# Renamed Product still showing old name in Catalog and on Store

Tags: magento2

Using Magento 2.2.5
After renaming a product and saving, the catalog still shows the old name. Edit the same product again and the change is there but the catalog listing doesn't seem to want to recognize it. Checking the actual store shows the old name as well.
I have run the reindexer and updated the cache repeatedly after trying different changes in hopes to make it recognize the new name.
Had this happen before and ended up deleting the product then recreating it. This one has order history we'd rather not lose so trying to find the correct way to get Magento 2 to recognize the new name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that are you able to see your change at the website level of the product edit? Magento by default considers website level values.

Comment: Website is not seeing the change. There are 2 other products that got the same change (version number in the Product Name) and they went through fine. We have many other products with the same format (3 line items with the same version number) that also have no problem. It's just this one particular line item that doesn't want to update in the catalog listing nor on the website. All appropriate settings match the other products that don't have this problem.